# I want to convert .docx to .dotx

Tags: python, ms-word, docx, file-conversion

I have populated some mail merge fields in a .docx file and now I want my script to convert the saved .docx file to a .dotx file. I am using Python 3.6.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from mailmerge import MailMerge
from datetime import date
from docx import Document
from docx.opc.constants import CONTENT_TYPE as CT
import csv
import sys
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# . . .

for i in range(0, numTemplates):
   theTemplateName = templateNameCol[i]
   theTemplateFileLocation = templateFileLocationCol[i]
   template = theTemplateFileLocation
   document = MailMerge(template)
   print(document.get_merge_fields())

   theOffice = officeCol[i]
   theAddress = addressCol[i]
   theSuite = suiteCol[i]
   theCity = cityCol[i]
   theState = stateCol[i]
   theZip = zipCol[i]
   thePhoneNum = phoneNumCol[i]
   theFaxNum = faxNumCol[i]

   document.merge(
       Address = theAddress 
   )

   document.write(r'\Users\me\mailmergeproject\test-output' + str(i) + r'.docx')
   #do conversion here
```

Here at the bottom is where I want to do the conversion. As you can see, I've written a file and it's just sitting in a folder right now

Comment: If you want to write a `.dotx` instead of a `.docx`, change that extension! Although it's only fair to tell you: if you do so and run your program again, the `.dotx` file will *also* just sit in a folder and do nothing. It is not entirely clear to me what you are expecting it to do.

Comment: I've already tried changing the extension - it throws an error whereas it won't when it's writing to a .docx

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code snippet for converting the .docx file to dotx.
You have to change the content-type while saving the document

```
pip install python-docx

import docx

document = docx.Document('foo.dotx')
document_part = document.part
document_part._content_type = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats- 
                              officedocument.wordprocessingml.template.main+xml'
document.save('bar.docx')
```

Comment: docx not support dotx format, " ValueError: file 'xxx.dotx' is not a Word file, content type is 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template.main+xml'"